# Can't update symfony 2.0.15

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm stuck here:

> Installing/Updating AsseticBundle
>   9c1b7269a4517d1ae94af2dc0d6d6fc4b31e6c10
>   HEAD is now at 41b5913 Merge pull request #27 from stof/disable_profiler
>   sh: /app/console: Permission denied
>   sh: /app/console: Permission denied

What's wrong with the repository? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you post both the definition of the assetic bundle in your deps and deps.lock file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears I needed to make my app/console chmod 777. I've been updating since 2.0.12, and find it strange that I'm only getting that error now.

Another suggestion was to make the git repository https; but that didn't work.